# What does "Arcate, sostenuto e come stà" mean?

Tags: translation

In a musical piece by Arcangelo Corelli, [Christmas Concerto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_Concerto_(Corelli)), he wrote an instruction: *Arcate, sostenuto e come stà*. Because this is music related (possibly specific to string instruments like violins) and is 17th century Italian, I'm not keen on Google translate and the like.

Why does he want from the players?

Comment: I hope this is a better place for this question than [music.se], which from my experience will have a harder time dealing with this. You might want to add a `music` tag since most musical terms are in Italian.

Comment: Oh, I was just about to suggest Music.SE as a better venue for such a question, since it seems to be about a quite technical indication about how to use the bow (*arcate* seem to allude to it) and how to play the piece.

Comment: @DaG It's a bit of both. I'm somewhat active there and I think that unless someone already played it they will have to translate anyway.

Comment: I think you might need a professional musician specialized on music of that era to figure out precisely what it means. [*Sostenuto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sostenuto) is fairly easy and I believe it to be standard music terminology and *come sta* means *as it is*, which I assume means that you have to keep the same tempo as the previous part. I have no idea about *Arcate* except that, as @DaG said, it is probably related to some particular techniques for stringed instruments (*arco* in Italian means *bow*).

Comment: Yes, @DenisNardin: apparently an *arcata* is a special way of playing the strings with the bow. See [here](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arcata/), item 4. Someone more knowledgeable than me about string instruments (easy), should translate it in Stringese...

Comment: If the verdict is to go to [music.se] then I'm fine with that :)

Comment: @DaG: "Arcata" non è un modo speciale di far suonare le corde. Ogni volta che si passa l'arco sulle corde di uno strumento ad arco si fa un'arcata.

Comment: E quindi secondo te perché Corelli lo specifica, @Charo? Forse in contrapposizione al pizzicato o ad altre tecniche?

Comment: @DaG: Questo avrebbe senso se precedentemente se avesse suonato pizzicato, ma non è il caso qui.

Comment: @user1803551: Could it be "arcate sostenute"?

Comment: "Arcate, sostenuto" doesn't seem to have much sense to me.

Comment: @Charo Apparently some places write it one way and other the other way. If it makes more sense with an *e* then that's fine by me.

Comment: "Come sta" probably means that music score must be interpreted exactly in the way the composer wrote it. It's baroque music: in this period it was a common practice for virtuoso performers to improvise ornamentations.

Comment: @Charo The instruction not to "improvise" is usually [*tasto solo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasto_solo). What would the whole expression mean by your translation then?

Comment: But I think that "tasto solo" refers to the basso continuo line, not to the melody lines.

Comment: If it's "arcate sostenute", "sostenute" would be an adjective referring to "arcate" meaning sustained.

Comment: "Arcate" is the plural of "arcata". Each way the performer passes the bow through the strings is called "una arcata".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression is probably "Arcate sostenute e come sta" as you can find [here](http://www.medieval.org/emfaq/cds/eum50202.htm). "Arcate, sostenuto" doesn't seem to make much sense.

"Arcate" is the plural of "arcata". Each way the performer passes the bow through the strings is called "[una arcata](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=arcata)".

If it's "arcate sostenute", "sostenute" would be an adjective referring to "arcate", which means "sustained". That is, the performers should pass the bow through the strings in a sustained legato way.

"E come sta" means "and as it is". It probably means that music score must be played exactly in the way the composer wrote it. It's important to note that it's baroque music: in this period it was a common practice for virtuoso performers to improvise ornamentations.

You can find a very interesting explanation of this concerto [here](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/75808/21m-220-spring-2007/contents/assignments/paper2_thaned.pdf).

Comment: Sostenuto indica il tempo, quindi è giusto sostenuto e non sostenute

Comment: In a [publicly available score](http://imslp.org/wiki/12_Concerti_Grossi,_Op.6_(Corelli,_Arcangelo)) I find “Arcate sostenute e come sta”

Comment: @egreg: Non ho trovato il termine nel link indicato

Comment: @JoeTaras: "Sostenuto" is sometimes used to indicate a tempo, but not always.

Comment: @JoeTaras It's in one of the “sublinks”.

Comment: Il link di Wikipedia sul Tempo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo . Suppongo che il termine "come sta" indichi l'assenza di cambio di tempo.

Comment: Su amazon esempi di "come sta" https://www.amazon.it/Sonata-cinque-Major-G-Allegro/dp/B01LCMWCTQ/ref=sr_1_31?s=dmusic&ie=UTF8&qid=1483354555&sr=1-31&keywords=come+sta  https://www.amazon.it/Sonata-No-Minor-Op-Andante/dp/B01BH6U9D8/ref=sr_1_36?s=dmusic&ie=UTF8&qid=1483354555&sr=1-36&keywords=come+sta

Comment: @JoeTaras: All these are examples of baroque music, so in all these examples it would probably mean what I have explained. See, for instance, http://www.irelandseye.com/aarticles/culture/music/traditional/notions.shtm.

Comment: @JoeTaras: Another source: https://books.google.es/books?id=mutaps6xlIIC&pg=PA444&lpg=PA444&dq=%22come%20sta%22%20corelli&f=false.

Comment: @Charo: About the second link, page 25 not in preview, so I can't read it. But "come sta" it's ok (without accent).

Comment: @JoeTaras: In fact, it's page 444. It says the following.

Comment: «Corelli's use of the phrase *ad libitum* in Op. 6, No. 8, has been interpreted in various ways. For example, some contend it was used to inform the performers that improvised ornamentation is permitted in this movement, in contrast with the earlier Grave that is marked *come sta* (as it stands), indicating that this slow movement should not be decorated. Deas (1953) argues that the tied note linking the preceding Allegro to the pastorale is an indication that the latter is not optional. I conclude that Corelli marked the pastoral, a traditional Christmas Eve movement, as optional in the ...

Comment: ... printed version so that the concerto could be played without the pastorale on occasions other than Christmas Eve.»

Comment: ok, good research

Comment: Ultimately, I can't tell if this is the correct answer, but given the research I think it deserves the correct answer mark. Thanks.